# How to detect if a windows machine is running IPV4 or IPV6?

Tags: windows, ipv6, ipv4

Is there anyway to determine if a windows computer is running IPV6 using native utilities, python or php?

Comment: Hans is absolutely right. You are implying xor, but in reality, it is inclusive or.

Comment: "Running" is different than "Has connectivity using...". I would rather use some kind of IPv6 probe (to Google IPv6 address, perhaps?). Quite a number of machines will configure IPv6 address, but the underlying network infrastructure won't allow IPv6 to go anywhere (think: your home gear supports IPv6, but ISP gear does not).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue, by trying to open up an IPv6 socket. If the system did not throw an error, then it is using IPv6.

```python
import socket

def isIPV6():   
    ipv6 = True
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    except:
        ipv6 = False
    return ipv6
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure. If `ipconfig` contains an `IPv6 Address` entry for a real interface, you've probably got IPv6 connectivity. There are also useful registry entries at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\TCPIP6`.

Answer (score 1):

Every computer ships with IPv4 at standard. IPv6 is only enabled on specific machines. But if you parse ifconfig/ipconfig then you should find yourself a IPv4/6 address in the output

Comment: Wrong, IPv6 is usually enabled by default, and will be used as preferred if a computer can get routable IPv6 address.

Comment: @StanTastic This answer is 6 years old when things were very different

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate the interfaces and check for an IPv6 address, like everyone else has stated.  Alternatives include trying to open an IPv6 socket or get Python to call [`WSCEnumProtocols()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742237%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Trying to open an IPV6 socket does the trick, take a look at my answer for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Jakob's approach is the simplest; you could pipe the result and do a match to see whether a network adapter has a valid IPv6 address.

Additionally, you could get this by fetching the Windows Management Instrumentation class [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217%28VS.85%29.aspx). The property `IPAddress` is an array of all the IP addresses associated with a network adapter and you can match against them to see if there is a `IPv6` address associated. But PS is a bit of an overkill, I'd go with Jakob's or Wyatt's answer unless you'd need to do something more intelligible and fancy (send an HTTP request; change some network rules; restart a service).